# Is it possible to keep a variable in a file, then import and use it in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have module with functions that return different proplists.
Module functions look like:

```
get_schema(auth) ->
    [
        {<<"login">>, [{string, required}]},
        {<<"password">>, [{string, required}]},
        {<<"id">>, [{string, required}]}
    ];

get_schema(update_password) ->
    [
        {<<"oldpassword">>, [{string, required}]},
        {<<"newpassword">>, [{string, required}]},
        {<<"id">>, [{string, required}]}
    ].
```

I then import this module from another module and fetch the proplists using the respective functions.

Is it possible to keep these proplists as variables, not as functions, that are accessible from other modules that import this one?

Comment: In Erlang you don't have to import a module before using it, because all modules are global. Those functions perform no computation, so there is no overhead when calling them. Function returning static value and variable are almost the same thing. Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use it the way it is?

Comment: It's fine and the issue is almost with my programming habits, where I am used to functions as pieces that calculate something and variables are just static entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest leaving the thing as it is now.

If you really want to use variable then simply assign the return value to a variable and use it this way:

```
AuthSchema = my_module:get_schema(auth),
```

This function is referentially transparent, which means that calling it and using its return value give the same result. Using separate module with functions without arguments (or with pattern match as in your example) for constants is fairly common practice in Erlang. For example look at the `translit` function [here](https://gist.github.com/devinus/450612).